# Can I use the Cut Rule to prove " a maximally consistent set ( of propositions) only entails its members" ( Shapiro's Classical Logic Article)

Tags: logic, soft-question, solution-verification, first-order-logic

Source : https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Dedu

---

In his Classical Logic article, Shapiro states that :

"if a set Γ is maximally consistent then Γ⊢θ if and only if θ is in Γ " .

The statement is not proved. As an exercice , I'd like to prove it, or , at leat, the $\implies$ direction.

My question : ***is the application of the Cut Rule in step (4) correct?***

In the rule of Cut ( " If Γ$_1$⊢ψ and Γ$_2$,ψ⊢θ, then Γ$_1$,Γ$_2$⊢θ ")  , ***can Γ$_1$ and Γ$_2$ be the same set?***

(1) Suppose $\Gamma$ is maximally consistent.

(2) Suppose also that $\Gamma\vdash \theta$.

(3) Suppose finally ( for refutation) that $\theta \notin\Gamma$. In that case $\Gamma\cup\{\theta\}$ is inconsistent ( by df. of " maximally consistent").

Now , by Theorem 12, we know that a set $\Gamma$ is consistent if and only if there is a sentence $\theta$ such that it is not the case that Γ⊢θ. This implies that an inconsistent set implies any sentence.

Since $\Gamma\cup\{\theta\}$ is inconsistent, it implies any sentence, in particular : $\Gamma\cup\{\theta\}\vdash\neg\theta$.

(4) Applying the Cut Rule, from our assumption $\Gamma\vdash \theta$ together with $\Gamma\cup\{\theta\}\vdash\neg\theta$, we can conclude that :  $\Gamma\cup\Gamma \vdash \neg\theta$, and therefore that $\Gamma \vdash \neg\theta$.

(5) We  both have $\Gamma\vdash\theta$ ( by hypothesis) and $\Gamma \vdash \neg\theta$, which means that $\Gamma$ is not consistent, which contradicts our main assumption.

Since the hypothesis $\theta\notin\Gamma$ leads us to a  contradiction this hypothesis is false.

(6) We can therefore conclude that : $\Gamma$ being supposed  maximally consistent , if $\Gamma\vdash\theta$ it must be the case that $\theta\in \Gamma$.

Comment: "can Γ1 and Γ2 be the same set?" Yes.

Comment: @MauroAlllegranza. Thanks.